# Escape json using \" in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this input
`{"a":["b","c","d"]}`

For whatever reason, I need output like this
`"{\"a\":[\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"]}"`

Instead of this (using JSON.stringify())
`'{"a":["b","c","d"]}'`

I know I can write some replacements or something. Is there any native Javascript method to do this？

Comment: where is the input coming from, why do you need to display it in json form? just escape the text (search htmlentities in js) or place it in a <pre> tag

Comment: "{"\"a\"":["\"b\"","\"c\"","\"d\""]}"
Try this

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a custom replace is that you risk making the string invalid JSON. Instead you can simply `stringify` it twice, which will properly escape all special characters such that it can be reliably parsed back to a valid javascript object.

```js
const input = { 'a': ['A string with "quotes"', "c", "d"] };

const string = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(input));
console.log(string);

const parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(string));
console.log(parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const a = {"a":["b","c","d"]}
const output = JSON.stringify(a).replaceAll('"', '\\"')
console.log(output)
```

Hope this helps